# Has many conditions in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

How to do this:

```
 has_many :space_mappings, -> { where(group_id: group_id) }, through: :category
```

That is - SpaceMapping and this model both has a group_id and they have to match. I could just make a method but I would like for this to be possible.

Here I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `group_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_SpaceMapping:0x007fe5ac118bd8>
```

I have done this instead:

```
def space_mappings
  category.space_mappings.where(space_id: Space.where(group_id: group_id))
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Just to have an association named `space_mappings` that are categories?

Comment: does "this model" have a `belongs_to` relation with categories and a `category_id` field on its table?

Comment: I have made a terrible mistake when asking the question. Category_id should have been group_id. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: That obscures more than it clarifies. What is a `group_id`? Presumably a foreign key for... something?

Comment: Well... This model has many SpaceMappings through the Category model. So far so good. The thing is that for that relation to be valid (in the context of the app) the group_id has to be the same too. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You must assign a value for category_id.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html (4.3.3.1 section).
It can help your for understanding details and clear concept.

Comment: Please see the question again - I made a mistake asking it - it should be correct now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If "this model" has a `belongs_to :category` relationship or a `has_one :category` relationship, then you shouldn't need that `where` clause at all. The whole point of "has many through" is to restrict the associated models to those that are associated with the model they're associated *through*

That is, you should just be able to do

```
belongs_to :category
has_many :space_mappings, through: :category
```

assuming that space mappings also belong to a category.

Comment: Please see the question again - I made a mistake asking it - it should be correct now. Sorry about that.